# Is there any simple\direct way to simulate\test MSAL JS $rootScope.$on("msal:acquireTokenFailure") event?

Tags: angularjs, token, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm trying to debug some JS code to acquire a token silently.

However I need to enter into this specific function that handles `acquireTokenFailure` event:

```
$rootScope.$on("msal:acquireTokenFailure", function (event, errorDesc, error)
{
    console.log("acquireTokenFailure:\n" + error + " - " + errorDesc);

    //msalService.acquireTokenSilent(['openid offline_access']);

    if (error.indexOf("consent_required") !== -1 || error.indexOf("interaction_required") !== -1)
    {
        msalService.acquireTokenSilent(['openid']).then(function (token)
        {
            debugger;

            // retry the API call...

        }, function (error)
           {
               debugger;

               console.log(error);
        });
    }
});
```

Is there any straightforward way to expire the token manually so that I can get into the JS function above?

By the way: I'm using this sample project [MsalAngularjsDemoApp](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/samples/MsalAngularjsDemoApp/app.js) that is specific to Angular JS.

I see [a question](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/810) like this got asked @ MSAL GitHub repo but there was no satisfactory answer so far...

Comment: Reopen the issue in GitHub and ask for specifics.

Comment: Hey @Jenny... opened this other one here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1077

Comment: I see it's closed already though...is that intentional?

Comment: @Jenny yep... :)